# Return calendar event details in an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a calendar in which if the user selects the date and it takes him to an event details page. On the event details page the data is displayed in a tabular format. So far so good. The problem is how to set the details of the event in the eventDetails function and return them to set the text.

Code:

```
  //get the data and split it
    String[] dateAr = date_string.split("-|\\||\\(|\\)|\\s+");
    m = Integer.parseInt(dateAr[6]);
    d = Integer.parseInt(dateAr[3]);
    y = Integer.parseInt(dateAr[8]);

    name = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.name);
    title = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.title);
    details = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.details);


    name.setText(name_details); //should get the info from the eventDetails method
    title.setText(title_details); //should get the info from the eventDetails method
    details.setText(event_details); //should get the info from the eventDetails method

  //event details
  public String eventDetails(int m, int d) {
    String holiday = "";
    switch (m) {
        case 1:
            if (d == 1) {
                holiday = "Some event";
            } else if (d == 10) {
                holiday = "Some event";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if ((d == 11) || (d == 12)) {
                holiday = "Some event";
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            if ((d == 1) && (d== 7)) {
                holiday = "Some event";
            }
            break;
    }

    return holiday;
}
```

The String `holiday` returns only one object. I want to get the name, title and details and set the corresponding element's text to it. How can I achieve this? How do I add the name, title and details as separate objects and return them as separate objects to set the text accordingly? DO I add them to an array? Something like for every event date:

```
String holiday[] = {"name of the event", "title of the event", "details of the event"};
```

If so, how do I return the array to set the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `class` that contains these event details and return an instance of it. For example:

```
public class Event
{
    public final String name;
    public final String title;
    public final String details;

    public Event(final String a_name,
                 final String a_title,
                 final String a_details)
    {
        name = a_name;
        title = a_title;
        details = a_details;
    }
};

public Event eventDetails(int m, int d) {
    if (some-condition)
        return new Event("my-name1", "my-title1", "mydetails1");
    else
        return new Event("my-name2", "my-title2", "mydetails2");
}

final Event e = eventDetails(1, 4);
name.setText(e.name);
title.setText(e.title);
details.setText(e.details);
```

Comment: I would like to add multiple events to one date? How would I do that? Something like `return new Event("my-name1", "my-title1", "mydetails1") return new Event("my-name2", "my-title2", "mydetails2");` but this isn't the right way.

Comment: @input, return a `List<Event>`. `List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>(); events.add(new Event(....)); events.add(new Event(...)); return events;`

Comment: @hjmd, okay I did that. Now when I change this code to `final List<Event> e = eventDetails(m, d);`, it marks `e.name` as error and throws the error: `name cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: You'll need to access the elements in the `List` individually. @input, it may be more productive if you raise a new question for what you want to achieve. More people will see it and respond.

Comment: I already have asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401191/return-multiple-calendar-events  Can you please help me out there?

Answer (score 0):

There two ways you can return, 1) as array you specified 2) Create HolidayVO with required variables and gettter/setters.

Based on case:

```
case 1:
    if (d == 1) {
       //Create holiday object with values;
    } else if (d == 10) {
        //Create holiday object with values;
    }
    break;
```