# Return Multiple calendar events

Tags: java, android, calendar

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386687/100747) by @hmjd helped me to set the text of multiple objects. But I have run into a problem now. A date can have multiple events and I would like to show all the events and their details on the same event details page. How can I do this?

Code:

```
public class Event
{
    public final String name;
    public final String title;
    public final String details;

    public Event(final String a_name,
                 final String a_title,
                 final String a_details)
    {
        name = a_name;
        title = a_title;
        details = a_details;
    }
};



final Event e = eventDetails(1, 4);
name.setText(e.name);
title.setText(e.title);
details.setText(e.details);

//event details
public Event eventDetails(int m, int d) {
    switch (m) {
        case 1:
            if (d == 10) {
                return new Event("event1", "my-title1", "mydetails1");
            }
            if (d == 28) {
                 return new Event("event2", "my-title1", "mydetails1");
                 return new Event("event3", "my-title2", "mydetails2"); //add another event on this date; obviously this is not the right way.
            }

            break;

    }

    return new Event("default_my-name2", "default_my-title2", "default_mydetails2");
}
```

Comment: Add the events to an ArrayList<Event> and then handle each event inside the ArrayList accordingly?

Comment: @adchilds, I did that. `//event details
public ArrayList<Event> eventDetails(int m, int d) {
     ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
        switch (m) {
   if (d == 15) {
    events.add(new Event("event1", "eventtitle", "event_Details"));
    events.add(new Event("event2", "eventtitle", "event_Details"));
    return events;
   }
        break;
  }
}` It's throwing an error on the line where I'm calling the eventDetails function: `final Event e = eventDetails(m, d);`  The error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<HijriEvents.Event> to HijriEvents.Event`

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're trying to store the return type of eventDetails (which returns an ArrayList of Event type) into a normal Event. You can't store an ArrayList into Event. Also, your switch statement does nothing as of right now (in the code you just supplied. It's fine in the original post)? 

    final event e

should be of ArrayList type. Then you can extract each Event from that ArrayList.

Comment: @adchilds, thanks for the explanation. could you please post a sample code because I tried to change `final Event e` to ArrayList type and it gave me many errors? Maybe I'm missing something somewhere? The switch statement works fine in the original post.

Comment: To store the events returned by eventDetails, you would do something like this:

`ArrayList<Event> e = new ArrayList<Event>();
e.add(eventDetails(1, 4)); // This adds one event to the ArrayList`

Then to access the Events stored in ArrayList e:

`Event one = e.get(0); // First Event in the ArrayList
Event two = e.get(1); // Second Event in the ArrayList
...
Event n = e.get(n); // nth Event in the ArrayList`

Comment: @adchilds, thanks. I did that. How would I set the event to the textbox? I did this `Event one = e.get(1); eventdetails.setText(one);` and it threw the error: `The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (HijriEvents.Event)`.

Comment: @adchilds, Thank you so much! I solved it! Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Just one last question, an event may have sometimes 1 event or sometimes it may have 2 or 3 events. Is there anyway I can add all the events without predefining them as `e.get(0)` i.e without extracting them the hard-coded way? Wouldn't `e.get(2)` throw an error if let's say, a particular doesn't have 3 events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the events returned by eventDetails, you would do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Event> e = new ArrayList<Event>();
e.add(eventDetails(1, 4)); // This adds one event to the ArrayList
```

Then to access the Events stored in ArrayList e:

```
Event one = e.get(0); // First Event in the ArrayList
Event two = e.get(1); // Second Event in the ArrayList
...
Event n = e.get(n); // nth Event in the ArrayList
```

If you want to make this dynamic instead of explicitly saying `e.get(0)`, you would loop over the size of the ArrayList as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++)
{
    Event ev = e.get(i);
    ev.doSomething();
    ev.doSomethingElse();
}
```